# how to debug font lock keywords error

Tags: debugging, emacs, elisp, syntax-highlighting, font-lock

How can I debug font lock keywords I write? For example

```
(progn
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil
   '(
     ;; ("hi1" . 'success)
     ("hi2" . (intern (concat "warn" "ing")))
     ))
  (font-lock-fontify-buffer))
```

will produce the following message in Messages buffer:

```
Error during redisplay: (jit-lock-function 1) signaled (wrong-type-argument stringp 22)
```

In order to see the call stack upon wrong-type-argument error, I invoke `toggle-debug-on-error` and Emacs still doesn't enter debugger upon font lock error.

Comment: As to why we get an error for that particular example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570224/how-does-a-progn-form-in-font-lock-keywords-work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

font-lock
 can be applied in different ways.  By default it is applied using 
jit-lock-mode, which applies it "lazily" (aka "just-in-time"), which has
 the disadvantage that it is applied at a time where we can't display 
message (or enter the debugger) because that would make us inf-loop.  So
 there are two ways to work around the problem:

- Use `jit-lock-debug-mode` (recently added to Emacs's development 
  code).
- Set `font-lock-support-mode` to nil, then turn font-lock off and then 
  back on.

Both options should change font-lock so that it is applied at a time 
where debugging can be used.