# How does a progn form in font-lock-keywords work?

Tags: emacs, elisp, syntax-highlighting, font-lock

Following code will visually replace "hello world" with "HW" by passing a progn form to font lock keywords.

```
(font-lock-add-keywords
 nil '(("\\(hello world\\)"
        (0 (progn (put-text-property (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1)
                                     'display "HW")
                  nil)))))
```

I've look into `C-h v font-lock-keywords` to see if this is a documented feature of font lock. The hello world element seemed to be of this form:

```
(MATCHER HIGHLIGHT ...)
```

which would mean that `(0 ...)` is HIGHLIGHT and the doc says

```
HIGHLIGHT should be either MATCH-HIGHLIGHT or MATCH-ANCHORED.
```

and

```
MATCH-HIGHLIGHT should be of the form:

 (SUBEXP FACENAME [OVERRIDE [LAXMATCH]])
```

So I guessed 0 was SUBEXP and `(progn ...)` was FACENAME. But if `(progn ..)` were a valid FACENAME, the following code would work but it doesn't work.

```
;;  (MATCHER . FACENAME)
(font-lock-add-keywords
 nil '(("goodbye lenin"
        . (progn (put-text-property (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1)
                                    'display "GL")
                 nil))))
```

That brings me to the question of how the first code works and whether it is relying on an undocumented feature.

---

**Update**:

Side note: simpler way of visual replacement without font lock errors

```
(font-lock-add-keywords
 nil '(("my llama"
        (0 (progn (put-text-property (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)
                                     'display "ML")
                  nil)))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work - but your `MATCHER` is not correct - the result of the match is not stored. This, for example does not work:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords
 nil '(("goodbye lenin"
        (0 (progn (put-text-property (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1)
                                    'display "GL")
                  nil)))))
```

while this does:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords
 nil '(("\\(goodbye lenin\\)"
        . (progn (put-text-property (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1)
                                    'display "GL")
                 nil))))
```

The documentation says: "`FACENAME` is an expression whose value is the face name to use.
Instead of a face, `FACENAME` can evaluate to a property list
of the form `(face FACE PROP1 VAL1 PROP2 VAL2 ...)`
in which case all the listed text-properties will be set rather than
just `FACE`."

Here, the `FACENAME` expression (`progn`) evaluates to `nil`, so no properties or faces are being set - the only effect that caused by `put-text-property`.

Comment: The `("\\(goodbye lenin\\)" . (progn..))` example works but somehow it generates  `Error during redisplay: (jit-lock-function 1) signaled (invalid-function progn)` in Messages, and when I type `(defun goodbye lenin)`, the word defun stops getting highlighted with font-lock-keyword-face as soon as I finish the closing paren.

Comment: Indeed. It seems to me that in the case of the latter syntax, the form is evaluated at `font-lock.el` line 1542 (emacs 24.2). There is a `funcall`, and `progn` is not a function, hence the error. Changing the `funcall` to `eval` removes the error, but I am not an expert on emacs font lock, so I cannot promise this does not break something. Also, I cannot find the reason why the whole line loses highlights when you type the next character after "lenin".

Comment: Anyway, I think the gist here is that yes, the definitions are equal so they should behave identically - but the two cases are implemented by two distinct pieces of code and they do not produce 100% identical results.

Comment: The reason why the whole line loses highlight is probably because of the font lock error. When an element in font-lock-keywords causes error, font lock sometimes give up on processing other elements after that element, and the element for highlighting the word defun is placed somewhere after the most recently added element for goodbye lenin.

Comment: Even after fixing the error by changing the `funcall` to `eval`, the highlights are lost, so that is not the (only) reason.

Answer (score 1):

One
 problem with `("goodbye lenin" . (progn (put-text-property 
(match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) 'display "GL") nil))` is that it is 
just another way to write: `("goodbye lenin" progn (put-text-property 
(match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) 'display "GL") nil)`, and these 
equivalences can lead to ambiguities, which is why in this case you get 
errors.

So the form `(MATCHER . HIGHLIGHT)`, `(match . FACENAME)` and such 
should only be used when `HIGHLIGHT` and `FACENAME` are not themselves 
lists.

Comment: Does this mean that `("bob" . 'warning)` is also ambiguous because it is the same as `("bob" quote warning)` and that it should rather be written as `("bob" (0 'warning))` or `("bob" 0 'warning)`?

Comment: Yes.  It might work as is, but the longer form is not that much longer, saving you from having to worry if it's ambiguous or not.